# jquery sqlite database text search engine

Tags: jquery-mobile, sqlite, search-engine

i am working on a search engine in jquery mobile I want to split words in an array for a database search the code I am using is:

```
var sear=$("#search").val();

var db = openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM DEMO WHERE (D_Indications LIKE ?);",
                ["%"+sear+"%"],        
                function (tx, results) {
                  $('#output').show();
                  var len = results.rows.length, i;
                  var row=results.rows.item(i);
                  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    $('#output2').append('<tr><td>'+ row.Cat_name +'</td><td>'+ row.Drug_Caty +'</td><td>'+ row.G_Name +'</td><td>'+ row.B_Name +'</td><td>'+ row.D_Indications +'</td></tr>').trigger('create');        
                  }
                });
});
```

I want it to split words after space and search each word individually in database.
For eg.  if a user types "hello world" I want it to search "%hello%" & "%world%" separately in the database

Comment: What is the result? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I get result. but I want to search each word in the search box from database.

Comment: for eg. if a user types "hello world" I want it to search "hello" & "world" separately in the database.

Comment: Please describe an example of how you want to convert the input into a query in you question.

Comment: I am working on this for a search engine which searches the database.
For eg. if a user types "hello world" I want it to search "%hello%" & "%world%" separately in the database

Answer (score 0):

You can define that by splitting it

```
   text = "Hello World"
   var SpaceCount = text.split(' ').length -1;
```

then you can define how many spaces you have by SpaceCount.

then have a condition:

```
if (SpaceCount==1){
  var lines = text.split(' ')
       $.each(lines, function(key, line) {


          var db = openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(function (tx) {
           tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM DEMO WHERE (D_Indications LIKE ?);",
            ["%"+ line +"%"],        
            function (tx, results) {
              $('#output').show();
              var len = results.rows.length, i;
              var row=results.rows.item(i);
              for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                $('#output2').append('<tr><td>'+ row.Cat_name +'</td><td>'+ row.Drug_Caty +'</td><td>'+ row.G_Name +'</td><td>'+ row.B_Name +'</td><td>'+ row.D_Indications +'</td></tr>').trigger('create');        
              }
            });
       }

}
```